# Unable to install app to device specified with targetSdkVersion:Tiramisu - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-tiramisu

I am currently doing some testing on Android 13 Tiramisu and am having trouble getting the app to install on my device.
I have installed Android Tiramisu Preview (Rev.4) in Android Studio.
I created a sample app and configured it as follows

```
// build.gradle
android {
    compileSdkPreview "android-Tiramisu"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 16
        targetSdkPreview "Tiramisu"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    ...
```

I then tried to install this app on my **Android 12** (not Tiramisu) device.
When I did so, I got the following error

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

List of apks:
[0] '/Users/myuser/dev/sample/MyApplication/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'
The application's minSdkVersion is newer than the device API level.
```

In build.gradle, I have specified `minSdk 16`, so it should be possible to install the app on an Android 12 device.
How can I solve this problem?
(This problem did not occur when targetSdkVersion was set to anything other than Tiramisu)

Comment: same issue faced on my device unable to run the app on the android 13 emulator

Comment: did you solve this issue i will be very thankful if you post answer as well thanks

Comment: There is no resolution yet.
I have reported this problem to issuetracker.google.com. Apparently there are several people suffering from the same issue.

Comment: @Peri could you please post here what the bug number is if you have it please? thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is working as intended: targeting / compile with a pre-release version of Android will only work on pre-release device, before SDK is final. The error returned could be clearer, as it is misleading right now.

Comment: And since Android 13 Beta 3, the SDK is final with SDK Level 33. Developer now can install apps targeting 33 on older Android versions.

Comment: can you give an example? I've been struggling here...

Comment: Could you please explain what you're having trouble with exactly? Don't understand an example of what. In any case now you can use compileSdkPreview 33 as it is final.